# R Shiny - How to use a tableOutput as vector or data.frame

Tags: r, shiny

Greetings and thanks for your help,

I can't use a data.frame (created on server.R) in ui.R.
The reason is obvious: a `tableOutput()` is not a data.frame nor a vector.
I need to do this because the `selectInput("ops",...)` receives that table from server.R, as it is the result of a function applied to an input there.
The function is long, so i just made this `data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))`. Anyhow, the point is the same.

### Question:

Even though i know why is not working, I am not able to make it work.
What I am looking for is a way to get the information from the `tableOutput()` in a table-like way, to use it in the `selectInput(choices = ...)` dropdown list.

If you run this code you'll notice the `selectInput()` is just showing options: "name", "id", "class".
I want it to show: 1, 2. or 3, 4. or 5, 6...

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel({p("")}),
            mainPanel({
                tabPanel("Asignar tipo",
                    selectInput(
                        "ops",
                        "Operations",
                        tableOutput("impsTabla"),
                        multiple=TRUE,
                        selectize=TRUE
                    ),
                    br(),
                    tableOutput("impsTabla")
                )
            })
        )
    ), 
    server = function(input, output){
        output$impsTabla<- renderTable(
            data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: If it is necessary to have the input to `tabPanel()` vary based on user input, see ?renderUI and ?uiOutput. But `output$impsTabla` is constant, so you can feed these values directly into `tabPanel()` without resorting to a reactive UI.

Comment: I got it working using `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()` (thank you!) though when i try to use `output$impsTabla` directly into the `selecInput(choices = ...)` i get this message: Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'output' not found

Comment: that is because output is not visible for the ui, only for the server... useful article: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html